# What does 'knowtest' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I was WhatsApping with my native English speaker friend when he wrote the following phrase:

> I have knowtest

Unfortunately, I lost the exact conversation this was said in. It was said in a context related to an online article. I said something along the lines of

> I haven't planned anything on Saturday yet. Have you seen that Sequel To Movie You Like has such good reviews?

I did ask him what the word means. He tried to explain, but I did not understand his explanation. I have asked him if he meant a type of exam, but it appeared to have nothing to do with a test or exam at all. Neither does it appear in any dictonaries I checked. What does it mean? It appears to have nothing to do with tests at all.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what his explanation was that you didn't understand? If it wasn't used to mean "knowledge test", I have seen some people online use "knowtest" and "knotest" to mean "notice(d)". It's a really terrible misspelling and it could be a joke or slang, like in this meme: https://memegenerator.net/instance/62217251/y-u-no-i-just-now-knowtest-someting-im-dumb that says "I just now knowtest someting Im dumb".

Comment: It is not a common word. It might be an error or a joke. But the question cannot be answered as stands.

Comment: @JamesK the fact that there’s an accepted answer disagrees with you ;)

Comment: The accepted answer is a guess.  How do you know it is correct?

Comment: @JamesK because it fits perfectly in the context. I added some more context that I can remember.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such word. Fairly sure this is a misspelling of "noticed".

> I have **noticed**

Comment: How did you actually get to this conclusion? It fits in the context perfectly, but knowtest and noticed don’t even look similar.

Comment: @belle-sophie no, but they *sound* similar. It would be an example of an *eggcorn*.